# 'float' Type Error Python, pandas

Tags: python, string, machine-learning, scikit-learn, typeerror

while iterating on a column in a  data frame with unicode - string data(dtype object) i the following error:

```
in text_pre_processing(text)  
2 # removing punctuation  
3 #text = text1(r'\n',' ', regex=True)  
----> 4 text1 = [char for char in text if char not in string.punctuation]  
5 text1 = ''.join(text1)  


**TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable**
```

**function used**

```
def text_pre_processing(text):
    # removing punctuation
    #text1 = text1(r'\n',' ', regex=True)
    text1 =  [char for char in str(text) if char not in string.punctuation]
    text1 = ''.join(text1)

    # removing all the stop words from corpus 

    #return text.split()
    return[word for word in text1.split() if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
```

I tried to see if the column im feeding into the function has any float values(sentence with only float values) but failed to do so because "pandas" considers alfa numeric and alpha values as data type "object", explicit type casting would not work.

anyone has idea of what is going wrong?

I am using this function as part of naivebayes algorithm analyser.

Data :
column 1 is the index

```
Column2

this is a good movie...#    

this is a bad movie $....     

this #movie was good ;) but some scenes were exaggerating
```

expected output :

```
[this, good, movie]    
[this, bad, movie ]    
[this, movie, good, some, scenes, were, exaggerating]
```

Comment: You could wrap `text` back to a string: `[char for char in str(text) if char not in string.punctuation]`

Comment: Why are you iterating over the column? I smell an XY problem. Please show your data and your expected output. Iteration is the worst thing you could do with a dataframe in terms of performance. I'm 99% sure `pd.Series.str.replace` is better suited to your problem.

Comment: @hoefling i tried this but it still did not work...and also tried explicitly casting column into string 
    D1['column'] = D1['column'].astype(str)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ i made some changes to the question hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn a float to string:

```
>>> str(3.14159)
'3.14159'
```